# I wanted to remove background shadow from video in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

**I WAS STUCK FROM LAST 1 MONTH n this issue not able to understand is this issue from my side or plugin issue .please try to help me out because app is live and need to solve as soon as possible.i have used chewiecontroller for playing video**

````
ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: res.data.length,
                            itemBuilder: (c, i) {

                              return Container(

                                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 27,right: 27,bottom: 20),
                                child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: 30,
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                      width: _screenWidth,
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                          horizontal: 14, vertical: 17),
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          color: mineColors.whiteColor,
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                          boxShadow: [
                                            BoxShadow(
                                                offset: Offset(0, 0),
                                                color:
                                                    mineColors.greyColorLight,
                                                spreadRadius: 1,
                                                blurRadius: 8),
                                          ]),
                                      child:              VideoItems(
                                        videoPlayerController: VideoPlayerController.network(

                                       commonClass.assetURL+res.data[i].link
                                        ),
                                        looping: false,
                                        autoplay: false,
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              );
                            });
    ```

Here is my video items widget
 
import 'package:chewie/chewie.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

class VideoItems extends StatefulWidget {
  final VideoPlayerController videoPlayerController;
  final bool looping;
  final bool autoplay;


  VideoItems({
     required this.videoPlayerController,
    required this.looping, required this.autoplay,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _VideoItemsState createState() => _VideoItemsState();
}

class _VideoItemsState extends State<VideoItems> {
  late ChewieController _chewieController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _chewieController = ChewieController(
      videoPlayerController: widget.videoPlayerController,
      aspectRatio:16/9,
      autoInitialize: true,


      autoPlay: widget.autoplay,
      looping: widget.looping,
      errorBuilder: (context, errorMessage) {
        return Center(
          child: Text(
            errorMessage,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _chewieController.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Container(
        height: 200,
        width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: Chewie(
          controller: _chewieController,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
````

**Here is my video items widget inside listview builder with videoitems widget.**

Comment: share more of your codes

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.